# Python 3- How to use socket to create a simple chat program?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, chat

I have been searching the internet to create a simple python 3 program which can send messages between two computers using socket. The problem I have encountered is that tutorials are python 2.

How do I create a simple messaging program using socket between two computers on a local network?

Comment: The socket interface itself has changed some... it deals in `bytes` not `str` so you need to encode and decode, but is mostly the same as ever. It should be easy to adapt most tutorials.

Comment: Smells like homework, I dunno.

Comment: This is not homework btw, I have been searching the internet for hours as a personal project.

Comment: Alternately, you could use a higher level messaging system like [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/) that "messagizes" data for you and implements several useful network patterns.

Comment: Bit of a read, but interesting: [zeromq chat](http://zeromq.org/code:examples-chat)

Comment: Thanks for your input! However I was more interested in making it using socket.

Comment: with socket is this problem that it is "low level" element and you have to do all on your own - ie. you don't know how long is message which you will receive and if you get full message or you get two message as one text  but you need it as separated messages. And you have to build own methods to control it - so you have to create own "protocol" (similar to HTTP or FTP).

Answer (score 3):

I can give you a simple example, it is working in my computer, my python version is 3.4.4

The Client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(("localhost", 3333))

str_recv = s.recv(1024)

print(str(str_recv))

str_send = "Hello, the world!"

s.send(bytes(str_send, 'utf-8'))

str_recv = s.recv(1024)

print(str(str_recv))
s.close()
```

The Server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(('localhost', 3333))

s.listen(5)
flag = 0
while True:
    connect, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connection Address:" + str(addr))

    str_return = "Welcome to visit my test socket server. Waiting for command."
    connect.sendto(bytes(str_return, 'utf-8'), addr)

    str_recv, temp = connect.recvfrom(1024)
    print(str_recv)

    str_return = "I got your command, it is " + str(str_recv)
    connect.sendto(bytes(str_return, 'utf-8'), addr)

    connect.close()
```

I hope it can help you. LOL

Comment: What is the 'b' infront of the message that is sent and how can I get rid of that?    __b'Welcome to visit my test socket server. Waiting for command.'
b"I got your command, it is b'Hello, the world!'"__

Comment: @ComputingCorn `b` means `bytes` - socket sends data as bytes. You can use `data.decode('utf-8')` or `str(data, 'utf-8')` to convert from bytes to string. And `text.encode('utf-8')` or `bytes(text, 'utf-8')` to convert string to bytes.

Comment: Yes, As @furas said!

Answer (score 0):

```
        #client side software    
    
        import socket
        import threading
        import subprocess
        import tkinter
        import tkinter.scrolledtext
        from tkinter import simpledialog
        from datetime import datetime
        import emoji
        host = socket.gethostname()
        port = 49153
        
        
        class Client:
        
            def __init__(self, host, port):
                self.ke = []
                self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                self.sock.connect((host, port))
                self.bx = 0
        
                msg = tkinter.Tk()
                msg.withdraw()
        
                self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("Nickname", "Please enter a nickname: ", parent=msg)
        
                self.gui_done = False
                self.running = True
        
                gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
                recieve_tread = threading.Thread(target=self.recieve)
                sd = threading.Thread(target=self.recive1)
                sd.start()
                recieve_tread.start()
                gui_thread.start()
        
            def gui_loop(self):
                self.win = tkinter.Tk()
                self.win.configure(bg="lightGray")
                self.win.title("FON CHAT")
                self.win.iconbitmap()
                # self.text_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Chat: ", bg="lightgray")
                # self.text_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
                # self.text_label.grid(padx=20, pady=5)
        
                self.text_Area = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win, font=('Arial', 20), height=15)
                self.text_Area.grid(row=0, column=0)
                self.text_Area.config(state='disabled')
        
        
        
                self.msg_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Massage: ", bg="lightgray")
                self.msg_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
                self.msg_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=5)
        
        
        
                self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win, height=5)
                self.input_area.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=5)
        
                massage = f'{self.nickname}'
                self.sock.send(massage.encode('utf-8'))
        
                self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, text="send", command=self.write)
                self.send_button.config(font=('Arial', 12))
                self.send_button.grid(row=3, column=0)
        
                self.participantarea = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win)
        
                self.participantarea.config(width=20)
                self.participantarea.grid(row=0, column=1)
                self.participantarea.config(state='disabled')
        
                self.chat_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, text="CHAT")
                self.chat_button.grid(row=4, column=1)
        
                self.gui_done = True
                self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)
        
                self.win.mainloop()
        
        
            def write(self):
                massage = self.input_area.get(1.0, 'end-1c')
                self.sock.send(f'{datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")}, {self.nickname}&**&* {massage}'.encode('utf-8'))
                self.input_area.delete(1.0, 'end-1c')
        
            def stop(self):
                self.running = False
                self.win.destroy()
                self.sock.close()
                exit(0)
        
            def participates(self):
                connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                connection.connect((host, 9098))
                name = connection.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if name != '':
                    self.participantarea.config(state='enabled')
                    self.participantarea.insert('end', name)
                    self.participantarea.yview('end')
                    self.participantarea.config(state='disabled')
        
        
        
            def recieve(self):
                while self.running:
                    try:
                        massage = self.sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                        spillitted = massage.split("&**&*")
                        if ':(' in massage:
                            ksfds = massage.find(':(')
                            k = emoji.emojize(':frowning_face:')
                            massage = str(massage).replace(':(', str(k))
        
                        elif ':)' in massage:
                            ksfds = massage.find(':)')
                            k = emoji.emojize(':grinning_face_with_big_eyes:')
                            massage = str(massage).replace(':)', str(k))
        
                        elif ':|' in massage:
                            ksfds = massage.find(':|')
                            k = emoji.emojize(':neutral_face:')
                            massage = str(massage).replace(':|', str(k))
        
                        if massage == "NICK":
                            self.sock.send(self.nickname.encode('utf-8'))
        
        
                        else:
                            if self.gui_done:
                                t = massage.replace('&**&*', '')
                                self.text_Area.config(state='normal')
                                self.text_Area.insert('end', t + '\n')
                                self.text_Area.yview('end')
                                self.text_Area.config(state='disabled')
        
                    except ConnectionAbortedError:
                        break
        
                    except:
                        print("Error")
                        self.sock.close()
                        break
        
        
            def recive1(self):
               self.sock.send(self.nickname.encode('utf-8'))
               while self.running:
        
                    try:
                        self.massage12 = self.sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                        self.splited = self.massage12.split('&**&*')
        
                        if self.splited[1] not in self.ke:
                            self.participantarea.config(state='normal')
                            self.participantarea.insert('end', self.splited[1] + '\n')
                            self.text_Area.yview('end')
                            self.participantarea.config(state='disabled')
                            self.ke.append(self.splited[1])
        
                        if self.gui_done:
                            t = self.massage12.replace('&**&*', '')
                            self.text_Area.config(state='normal')
                            self.text_Area.insert('end', t + '\n')
                            self.text_Area.yview('end')
                            self.text_Area.config(state='disabled')
                        else:
                            pass
        
                    except IndexError:
                        pass
        
        
        
        tread = threading.Thread(target=Client, args=(host, port))
        tread.start()

#server side software
import socket
import threading


host = socket.gethostname()
port = 49153


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((host, port))

s.listen()

s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s2.bind((host, 60001))
s2.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []

fclients = []
fnicknames = []




def broadcast(massage):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(massage)




def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:

            # now = datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")  # time object
            # date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  # date object
            massage = client.recv(1024)
            # massage = f'[{date}] {now}: {massage}'
            broadcast(massage)



        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break


def recieve():
    while True:
        client, address = s.accept()
        print(F"Connected with {address}, {client}")
        # client.send("NICKNAME?".encode('utf-8'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024)
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        print(f'{client} + {nickname} + {address}')
        broadcast(f"{nickname} connected with server \n".encode('utf-8'))
        # client.send("connected to server".encode('utf-8'))
        clients.append(client)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client, ))
        thread.start()



print("server is running")
recieve()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).